# Curriculum vitae with publication image

Tags: graphics, positioning

I would like to insert small image for my publication list, similar to [this one](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vector/ParninCV.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Can you add a MWE please ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Take a look, perhaps, at `pdfpages` which would allow you to include a page of the PDF, scaled down, as an image. If you wish to include many such images, you might prefer to create scaled versions outside TeX and then just use `pdfpages` to include them. (This will make the images and your file smaller, and reduce compilation time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the construction of a resume, you can use a regular `\marginpar` to place items in the margin. Below I've wrapped this in a macro to align the top margin of the image with the top of the item. Other alignments are also possible, perhaps with the help of [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\insertgraphic}[2][]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \marginpar{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{%
      \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,#1]{#2}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \insertgraphic{example-image-a}\lipsum[1]
  \item \insertgraphic{example-image-b}\lipsum[2]
  \item \insertgraphic{example-image-c}\lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\reversemarginpar` switches content to the left margin.